# Apple requiring all app updates to built with iOS 12 SDK by March 2019 Question

Tags: ios, ios12

I'm currently using Xcode 9 but I have downloaded and "installed" the iOS device support files for 12.

Am I good to go for the March iOS 12 deadline?

Is satisfying the requirement as simple as submitting a new build when needed with my current setup or is more work required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to migrate to Xcode 10 to get the iOS 12 SDK support files.  Your app must be build with this iOS 12 sdk support.  This is not the same as pulling iOS 12 device support into Xcode 9 from Xcode 10.x versions.  Currently, going directly to 10.1 is the best move.  Fortunately, Swift 3 and 4 are currently supported in Xcode 10.1.  So if you are still on Swift 3 you will not have to also migrate your swift version.

Xcode 10.2 (currently in beta) will add support for swift 5.  Migrating from Xcode 10.1 to 10.2 will require you to be on Swift 4.2 as a minimum version, with Swift 5 being recommended.

After the deadline, any app submissions will need to be built with Xcode 10 or better, or else they will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've got a non-apple hard drive that is preventing me from doing the update. After pulling in the support files I was able to successfully build and deploy a app to a iPhone running iOS 12.2 beta.

Comment: So that is the difference between pulling in support files and building with the iOS 12 sdk.   Support files will allow you to build to an iOS 12 real device on unsupported versions of Xcode.  Being on a supported version (Xcode 10) allows you to develop iOS 12 specific features.

Comment: But you won't be able to submit an app update using iOS 12.2 beta (at least, you certainly can't do it now).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The app I'm concerned about has no specific iOS 12 features being used. Would the restriction still remain. Apologies for dragging this out. I'm just trying to get as clear a picture as I can.

Comment: For your app you set an os target, but this is always a base version for minimum support.  Meaning you set it to 8, you support 8 and above.  Set it to 12 you support 12.0 and above.  This can all be done while building with the iOS 12 sdk.  That is the part that is mandatory.  It does not matter if you are implementing iOS 12 features or not.  The app I work on does not have any iOS 12 specific features and were also stuck at 9.1.  We all just upgraded to avoid this submission issue.