# Error ITMS - 90725 : "SDK Version Issue."

Tags: ios, sdk, version

> Error ITMS 90745: SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later

I'm facing this issue since three weeks, can't upload my app on app store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple requiring all app updates to built with iOS 12 SDK by March 2019 Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795692/apple-requiring-all-app-updates-to-built-with-ios-12-sdk-by-march-2019-question)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795692/apple-requiring-all-app-updates-to-built-with-ios-12-sdk-by-march-2019-question). You need to update xCode and build against version 12.1 or greater.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked.